# "Request page too large", Best way to refactor?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, refactoring

The following code should check if either a # or @ symbol has been found in a string. The regex should find each and every @ or # (kind of like Twitter does)and should either place each instance it found into the `messages` table (if it was an @ symbol), or if it was a # symbol it should insert the instance into the `hashtags` table or update an existing record if the hashtag is already in the table.
Currently, the script itself works fine, but when using the code with javascript through AJAX, the console responds by saying the requested entity (this script) is too large (or something of that caliber). I'd assume its getting stuck in an endless loop, but so far I haven't found a (working) better way to do this. So, what would be a better way of coding this?

```
if (preg_match_all("/[@]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/i", $post, $matches)) {
        for ($i = 0;$i <= $matches;$i++) {
            $match = str_replace("@", "", $matches[$i]);
            foreach($match as $key=>$mVal) {
                $uMSQL = "INSERT INTO `messages` (`to`, `from`, `message`, `sent`) VALUES (:to, :from, '<p>tagged you in a post</p>', NOW())";
                $uMQ = $con->prepare($uMSQL);
                $uMQ->bindParam(':from', $author, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $uMQ->bindParam(':to', $mVal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $uMQ->execute();
            }
        }
    }
    if (preg_match_all("/[#]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/i", $post, $hashtags)) {
        for ($h = 0; $h <= $hashtags; $h++) {
            $htMatched = $hashtags[$h];
            foreach($htMatched as $key=>$htVal) {
                $htCheck = "SELECT COUNT(hashtag) FROM `hashtags` WHERE `hashtag` = '$htVal'";
                $htQ = $con->query($htCheck);
                $htExistence = $htQ->fetchColumn();
                if ($htExistence >= 1) {
                    $addTU = "UPDATE `hashtags` SET `used` = used+1 WHERE `hashtag` = '$htVal'";
                    $updateHT = $con->exec($addTU);
                } else {
                    $htMSQL = "INSERT INTO `hashtags` (`hashtag`) VALUES (:hashtag)";
                    $htMQ = $con->prepare($htMSQL);
                    $htMQ->bindParam(':hashtag', $htVal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $htMQ->execute();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

AJAX

```
 function sendData() {
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://localhost/NextIt/ajax/sendPost.php";
    var txtField = window.frames['richTextField'].document.body.innerHTML;
    var access = document.getElementById('postTo').selectedIndex;
    var acc = document.getElementById('postTo').options;
    var accss = acc[access].text;
    var vars = "post="+txtField+"&access="+accss;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (hr.readyState === 4 && hr.status === 200) {
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        $('status').innerHTML = return_data;
        window.frames['richTextField'].document.body.innerHTML = '';
    }
}
    hr.send(vars);
    $('status').innerHTML = "Posting...";
}
```

The post_max_size is 8M.

Comment: what does looking for strings to do db inserts have to do with page too large for ajax? Please put more effort in explaining your problem end to end with proper details

Comment: Just updated OP. Better?

Comment: not really...still all about loops for hashtags. No idea if sending/recieving with ajax, specific errors etc...or what server processing has to do with ajax at all

Comment: I still have the same question - the problem is with the request being too large for AJAX? Where's the AJAX code, and what is it returning? That seems more relevant than your server side code

Comment: Cool, so you're POSTing the data. Can you check post_max_size in your php.ini? And which browser are you testing in?

Comment: Ok well tell me what you'd like to know and I'll try my best to answer. It is sending the data to a PHP script through AJAX Post. The only "error" I'm getting is in the console (e.g. "Data too big") AJAX isn't returning anything (not supposed to) There isn't really a "problem" that I can really define. The script works, but something is causing the data to exceed limits.

Comment: Post_Max_size is 8M. Browser: Chrome, although the problem persists in other browsers. E.g Opera, Firefox, etc